# Image not Showing (Can see image in inspect element)

Tags: permalinks, images, templates

[image]I am new to WordPress. I have design a site.
My images are not displaying on the web pages, they were working fine yesterday but when I checked them now they are invisible, I have double checked the URL and also checked inspect element. But still cant find the issue.

The URL to website is [HERE](http://daewoocab.com.pk/home-page-centre/)

Please go below and enter pick-up and drop-off location and then click on calculate fare button, You will see a div which is missing images and distorted images.

**I am using wordpress 4.5.3 and AVADA THEME**

**Have any solution ?**

Comment: Please include the php that is supposed to generate the images. Also, I saw a background image on localhost. That won't work.

Comment: You need to update the permalinks under `settings->permalinks`

Comment: I have upgraded all the URL's but still now working some images

Comment: @cjbj there is no PHP, there is javascript, please check now, you sill see two images are shown but two are still missisng

Comment: @Ĭsααctիεβöss How to update permalinks ?

Comment: We can't access: "http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/howitworks2.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: login to your wp-admin and click `Settings->General` make sure `site address` is `http://daewoocab.com.pk/home-page-centre/` Also you need to change the same in `wp-options` table. You need to log-in to PhpMyadmin or similar on your server. Contact your host server admin for modifying the database.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I have changed the images src, Please see now

Comment: No you didn't... I'm still seeing the same urls..

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the image url's. Currently they are localhost, presumably because you have developed your site locally. If you update the image url's to the current domain, then they will display.

Comment: Please check the pick up loc image, its URL is on server but still not showing "http://daewoocab.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/pickup_loc.png"

Comment: I have upgraded all the URL's but still now working some images

Comment: That URL gives a 404. either re upload and relink your images, or change the image URL's in the database.

Comment: Do you have any caching plugins? If so, try and flush the cache to see if that works.

Comment: I dont have any caching plugin

Comment: All images are still localhost. The answer above will fix your issue. You need to either re upload your images and then re link them in the correct places, or change the domains in the database from localhost/path/to/image to the correct domain.

Comment: I have updated the question with the image, You can see there is links to live server images

Comment: Currently your images are this http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/daewoo_cab-1.png change the http://localhost:8080/ part to http://daewoocab.com.pk/ in the database.

Comment: You can test this by uploading a new image to your site via the admin media library at http://daewoocab.com.pk/home-page-centre/ and then adding it to a page. If the image displays, then my solution will work.

Comment: I have tried to upload  a new image and then links it to the page, but still same issue

Comment: All your images are there. Your default URL is wrong. You can change this in Settings --> General and update both urls and then click save. Your URL should be http://daewoocab.com.pk/ NOT http://daewoocab.com.pk/home-page-centre/ then go to Settings --> Permalinks and just click save to update your Permalinks. This should solve the issue.